# How old is Marguerite?

Tags: one-piece

As far as I checked in Google, there is no direct reference for the age of Marguerite - she was one of the female tribe members on Amazon Lily who've found Luffy.

Her age is ambiguous at best, as everything seems to qualify between 14 and 24 - or even beyond, knowing the way Oda handles age.

Is there anything known about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you said, her age hasn't been officially revealed yet. Judging from her physique and face, she could be anywhere from 16 to 24 years old, but until it is brought up in-story or Oda clarifies it in an SBS, her age will remain unknown.

EDIT: The Vivre Card Databook Vol. 4 finally revealed Marguerite's age; she is 16 pre-timeskip, and 18 post-timeskip.

Comment: It's funny how you say "yet". I highly doubt they will ever take him up again.

Comment: @Bálint  Never underestimate Oda's attention to detail... especially when it comes to young women.  Juggling the minutiae of thousands of unique characters is his bread and butter.